# C++ Get substring given start/end line/column numbers

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, substring

Given a `std::string` such as `"THE QUICK\nBROWN FOX JUMPED ON\nTHE CAT"`:

- There are three lines (separated via the `\n` character). The line number can be denoted as `int line_no` which incriments every time a `\n` is reached. Therefore it starts at 0 for the line `"THE QUICK"` and ends at 2 for `"THE CAT"`.
- A column number is `int col_no` represents how many characters before it are in a line. Therefore given line 1, "BROWN FOX JUMPED ON" if `col_no = 2` the character would be pointing to `'O'`. The `col_no` resets to 0 for the start of a new line.

If I wanted to extract the following string `"QUICK\nBROWN FOX"`, this can be achieved by getting the string between the ranges:

```
int min_line_no = 0; // the substring begins on line 0
int max_line_no = 1; // the substring ends on line 1
int min_col_no = 5;  // the substring character position starts at column 5 (on line 0)
int max_col_no = 8; // the substring character position ends at column 8 (on line 1)
```

In order to form the substring `"QUICK\nBROWN FOX"`, it will first look to line 0 (`min_line_no`). It will check to see if `max_line_no` is the same as `min_line_no`. If it is, it will get all the characters in the range `min_col_no` to `max_col_no` on line 0. If `min_line_no` and `max_line_no` are not the same, it will grab all the characters after `min_col_no` in `min_line_no` i.e. "QUICK\n". Then it will iterate the line_no and check to see if it's equal to the `max_line_no`. If it isn't - it'll grab the entire line and concat it to what it's extracted so far, and then iterate `line_no` and do the same for the next line. If line_no is the same as `max_line_no`, it will extract all the characters on the line up till and including `max_col_no` i.e. "BROWN FOX".

Is there a way of achieving this string extraction technique using standard library methods or an pre existing algorithm that can do this?

Comment: There are very, very few things that are "easy" in C++, the hardest and the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. Most tasks must be implement by implementing the appropriate logic. This is what must be done here, since there is no "standard library method" for something like this.

Comment: Are the line lengths the same, and are they always going to be 8 characters?

Comment: @cigien It will not always be 8 characters, the length of a line is determined when '\n' is encountered. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: if the row width is always constant over all rows (for example if its sometimes 42 instead of 10, just find it off the first line)- same way as treating an array... convert a row, col to a linear index : index=line*10+col.  after that a substring call should be trivial (min_index, max_index-min_index+1)

Comment: Your easiest approach to mapping 2D coordinates to an element of a string may be to just write that function yourself.  If you know the coordinates are valid, such a function should only be a few lines.

Comment: @Tom At a guess, some of the downvotes might be because you did not really explain your goal. Rather, you gave an example and expected everyone to fill in the details correctly. Some things you should consider adding to the question (if these are accurate, as I am guessing): 1) An actual definition of the coordinate system. Something like "Line numbers start at 0 and increment each time a `\n` is encountered."? "Column numbers start at 0 and increment with each character, but reset to 0 for the character after `\n`."? "The `\n` characters themselves do not have coordinates."?

Comment: 2) An actual definition of your range. It is strictly a substring? It goes from the character at `min_line, min_col`, progresses through the string until it reaches `max_line, max_col`? The fact that your `min_col` equals your `max_col` is merely an unfortunate coincidence? (Like your choice of equal lines lengths is an unfortunate coincidence?) If you're wondering why this definition matters, consider the possibility of the coordinates defining a rectangle. This is ruled out by your example (the result would be `"QN"`) but it does demonstrate that your intent is not the only possible way.

Comment: @Tom Clarifying the question more will help, It's hard to understand what the problem is and what you're trying to achieve with this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, I have updated the question with more details.